Data structure in Java for finding time overlapping events
The best way to explain is by example:
Data: [1,5] ,[2,7], [9,12]
input: 4
output: [[1,5] ,[2,7]]
input: 8
output: []
input: 11
output: [[9,12]]
Is there an efficient Java/Kotlin for that? (also not overloading the GC)
Edit: I see y'all have many good qustions, so I will clarify my question.

I expect Log(n) in the searching.
The data is an object that has "start" and "end" as Systerm.CurrentTimeInMillis() and an Id.
Louis Wasserman is right. Interval tree seems the right path, but all implementation that I found is not good.


I assume you expect at least O(log(N)). Interesting question, hmm.

Not a ready to use data structure, but we could probably transform overlapping ranges into a flat list of disjoint ranges (but more of them): [1], [2, 5], [6, 7], [9, 12]. Each flattened range is connected to a list of original ranges. Then we could find a range by binary search. It will be O(log(X)) where X is a number of flattened ranges. My gut feeling says X can't be larger than 2 * N, so technically it is still O(log(N)).

Check out Span: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/util/Span.java

Is there any constraint to the data (e.g. min value, max value, number of occurrences etc)? What are you trying to solve exactly (the explanation is clear but I can't map it 100% to a real life use case)?

@MatteoNNZ I think there are many real life uses for this. Say we have calendar events and we need to find events happening at a given time.

Is there an efficient Java/Kotlin what for that? Data structure? Are you just looking for the name of a data structure? That doesn't seem very useful. Are you expecting us to write the code to solve the problem you've presented? That's not what SO is here for. Try something, come back when you've hit a blocker. It's unclear what you're after. Please edit your question to clarify.

It sounds like you're looking for interval trees.

@broot yep that's what I thought, and that's why I asked for constraints. If those are hours (0-23) I would adopt an approach which is a bit different than if the algorithm was handling unconstrained data

@broot I think [1, 1] would be easier to work with than [1]

By "time overlapping", did you mean time-of-day ranges? And does "input 4" mean 04:00 time of day?

@Bohemian Yes, I made a mistake in my comment and couldn't edit it. I meant a range <1, 1>.

On the one hand, the duplink provided is (IMO) not a good match to the OP's problem.  On the other hand, the question has (IMO) serious unresolved problems (as per the comments), so I'm not convinced that the effort to find a better duplink (or write an answer) is warranted at this stage.

@LouisWasserman Yes, thank you. I found the right implementation of what i needed. https://github.com/lodborg/interval-tree I would give you a Checked answer if you would answer it.
